# Making an image fade to a color on hover / mouseover jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 3 images I want to have a fade effect with colors on hover / mouseover event.

**This is my code until now**

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Choose Category</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="aindex.css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <img class="top" id="hover1" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" align="left" width="33%" />
    <img class="top" id="hover2" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" align="left" width="33%" />
    <img class="top" id="hover3" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" align="left" width="33%" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what have you tried? There's no attempt here to actually achieve your stated goal. Did you research it? https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=make+image+fade+on+mouseover&oq=make+image+fade+on+mouseover&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.4279j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Check the answer below. The easy workaround to make feel like a color has been added on mouse hover.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pure CSS solution. This one fades out the image on hover and reveals the background that is set for the `div`.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

img:hover {
  animation: fadeout .5s ease forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeout {
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="red"><img src="http://placehold.it/100/333333"></div>
<div class="blue"><img src="http://placehold.it/100/666666"></div>
<div class="green"><img src="http://placehold.it/100/000000"></div>
```

Comment: Read the question first it says that JQuery way not the CSS way.

Comment: Don't argue with me just because i have done proper comment in yours. Your answer do not have any point here. Playing around with opacity gives the feel of color change so stop arguing with me,

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked for a jQuery solution, here you go:

```js
$(".wrap").hover(function() {
    $(this).children("span").fadeOut();
}, function() {
    $(this).children("span").fadeIn();
});
```

```css
.wrap {
    position: relative;
    width: 180px;
    height: 75px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color:blue;
}
.wrap span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background: url('https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg');
    background-size:cover;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap"><span></span>Hello</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the opacity in Cascading Style Sheet. The value of opacity is from 0 to 1

```
hover1:hover {
    opacity: 0.2;}
hover2:hover {
    opacity: 0.2;}
 hover3:hover {
    opacity: 0.2;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a JQuery function like this which will add the css for `opacity` dynamically when you `hover` over the image and remove your mouse pointer from the image.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".top").on("mouseenter", function(){
        $(this).css('opacity','0.7');

    });

    $(".top").on("mouseleave", function(){
        $(this).css('opacity','1');
    });
});
```

For your work around and simplicity here is the added link to [PLUNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/iCrmdxIGDJBTiOQAQ38r?p=preview)

Comment: Read the question first. What optional color does your solution fade in to?

Comment: Don't argue with me just because i have done proper comment in yours. Your answer do not have any point here. Playing around with opacity gives the feel of color change so stop arguing with me,